# SQL IS NOT NULL not working

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to write a short SQL query (in MySQL Workbench) that outputs the number of fails in a subject if it has been failed by more than one student.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT CONCAT(area, yearlevel, code) AS SubjectCode, Count(student)
FROM StudentTakesSubject
WHERE result < 50 AND result <> NULL
GROUP BY code
HAVING Count(Student) > 1;
```

The problem is it keeps outputting the count which contains the Null record even though I have specified in the query to not count them (or at least I thought I did...).

**EDIT :** 
It was the `GROUP BY` clause that went wrong! As **Gordon Linoff** has pointed out in his answer, it should have been `GROUP BY SubjectCode` and that magically solved the problem.

Thank you all for the constructive insights.

Comment: SQL SERVER or MySQL

Comment: Change `result <> NULL` by `result IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Not way it will count `NULL` result records `result < 50` will filter out `NULL's`

Comment: Your title has the correct syntax.  You seem to know what to do.  However, your query as written should return no rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed! When I use <> it returns nothing, when I use IS NOT NULL it returns the wrong count...

Comment: @CookieJar Show us sample data and expected ouput so we can understand that wrong output. Because there is no way `IS NOT NULL` isnt worling

Comment: `CONCAT(area, yearlevel, code) ... GROUP BY code` - You should not use columns in the SELECT clause that are not in the GROUP BY clause (except if they are functionally dependent on `code` - but that would be a bad design).

Comment: Keep in mind that <> NULL will never evaluate to true. Also in your query it is not needed anyway. Any value that is < 50 is already NOT NULL.

Comment: it's oke when code is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE key then the SQL is okay @PaulSpiegel... but you don't know in this case so i understand your comment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland grouping by a unique key (or PK) doesn't make sence for one table in FROM clause.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah as Gordon Linoff has pointed out I needed to change the Group By from code to SubjectCode and that has indeed solved the problem!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written:

```
SELECT CONCAT(area, yearlevel, code) AS SubjectCode, Count(student)
FROM StudentTakesSubject
WHERE result < 50 AND result <> NULL
GROUP BY code
HAVING Count(Student) > 1;
```

This query should return no rows.  Why?  `result <> NULL` returns `NULL` as a boolean value (to a close approximation all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`). `AND NULL` evaluates `NULL` -- and `NULL` is not true.  All rows are filtered out.

The `NULL` comparison is actually superfluous.  The `result < 50` will also filter out `NULL` values.

Looking at the rest of the query, you have another issue.  The `GROUP BY` is on `code`.  It should really be on `SubjectCode` -- the result of the `CONCAT()`.  In fact, when concatenating different columns, I would recommend using a separator, say `CONCAT_WS(':', area, yearlevel, code)`.  Of course a separator may not be desirable for this particular situation.

Comment: But in my data records I clearly count there should only be two while it still outputs 3... Unless my eyes are all lying to me which I have done multiple counting by hand...

Comment: Well magically, after changing group by to SubjectCode, the problem has been solved...

Comment: Thank you kind sir, to make it clear for others to see in the future would it be possible for me to answer to my own question while referring to your suggestions as the primary cause that solved this problem.

Comment: Or you can simply edit the group by clause and edit a few so that others would see what went wrong.

Comment: Note that grouping by an expression or an alias of an expression no index can be used. Instead i would group by the columns used in the expression - `GROUP BY area, yearlevel, code`.

Answer (score 0):

`result NOT NULL` instead of `result <> NULL`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(area, yearlevel, code) AS SubjectCode, Count(student)
FROM StudentTakesSubject
WHERE result < 50 
AND result NOT NULL
GROUP BY code
HAVING Count(Student) > 1;
```

Comment: 'result IS NOT NULL' instead of 'result NOT NULL'

Answer (score 0):

result <> NULL will not work, why?

> When you compare nonnull expressions, the result is TRUE if the left
>   operand is not equal to the right operand; otherwise, the result is
>   FALSE.

check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-traditional?view=sql-server-2017) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query selects the number of students who have taken a subject with a code, year level, and area, where their result is less than 50 but not null, and groups the results by subject code. The HAVING clause filters the results to only include subject codes with more than one student who has taken the subject and has a result less than 50.

Here's a breakdown of the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(area, yearlevel, code) AS SubjectCode, Count(student)
```

This selects the concatenated subject code and the count of students who have taken the subject.

```
FROM StudentTakesSubject
WHERE result < 50 AND result <> NULL
```

This specifies the StudentTakesSubject table and filters the results to include only rows where the result is less than 50 and not null.

```
GROUP BY code
HAVING Count(Student) > 1;
```

This groups the results by subject code and applies a HAVING clause to filter the results to only include subject codes with more than one student who has taken the subject and has a result less than 50.

Note that the column student is used in the SELECT and COUNT clauses, but not in the GROUP BY or HAVING clauses. This is because the query is only interested in counting the number of students who have taken each subject, regardless of which specific students they are. The GROUP BY clause is used to group the results by subject code, so it's not necessary to include student in the grouping.